# pgadmin, sql, function inputday by table name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I made a function im pgadmin

---

```
create or replace function get_source2(a text)

returns integer as

$$
declare

    a text;

    geom geometry;

begin

    select get_source(geom) 

    from a;


end

$$

language plpgsql;
```

---

I want input a by table name
How can I do?
I try to like this

select get_source2('postgis.center')
but
ERROR:  relation "a" does not exist
LINE 2:  from a
help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call it as part of a regular select statement:

```
select get_source(geom), name, place
from location;
```

But that will be very inefficient as you are running the select inside the function for each and every row in the `location` table.